# Debugging code with a mix of functions, macros, and bash calls in elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to call a bash program [herbstclient](http://wwwcip.cs.fau.de/~re06huxa/herbstluftwm/herbstclient.html) from Emacs via [process-lines](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Synchronous-Processes.html).  I created a macro hc-call which actually calls herbstclient that is invoked by the function hc which is supposed to convert its numeric arguments into strings via stringify-numbers.

Needless to say it's not working.  Calling hc with "keybind" "Mod4-Shift-r" "reload" gives the error:

```
 *** Eval error ***  Wrong type argument: listp, stringified-args
```

I tried using edebug on hc and the output suggested stringify-numbers was working properly.  The function errored immediately on the hc-call.  Yet, when I run:

```
(hc-call ("keybind" "Mod4-Shift-r" "reload"))
```

it works as expected.  I then tried:

```
(setq sargs (list "keybind" "Mod4-Shift-r" "reload"))
(hc-call sargs)
```

and I got the same error. I don't know how to approach debugging this further.  Below is all the code:

```
(defmacro hc-call (args)
  "Call herbstclient to with the given arguments."
   `(process-lines "herbstclient" ,@args))

(defun stringify-numbers (args)
  "Take a list of random arguments with a mix of numbers and
  strings and convert just the numbers to strings."
  (let (stringified-args)
    (dolist (arg args)
      (if (numberp arg)
          (setq stringified-args (cons (number-to-string arg) stringified-args))
        (setq stringified-args (cons arg stringified-args))))
    (nreverse stringified-args)))

(defun hc (&rest args)
  "Pass arguments to herbstclient in a bash process."
  (let ((stringified-args (stringify-numbers args)))
    (hc-call stringified-args)))
```

Why would it complain stringified-args isn't a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike most expressions, macro arguments are passed *unevaluated*.

This is why `(hc-call ("keybind" "Mod4-Shift-r" "reload"))` does not result in an error!

It therefore follows that `(hc-call sargs)` is passing the symbol `sargs` to the macro, rather than the list to which it would otherwise evaluate.

If you wish your macro to process a variable in this way, you could change `,@args` to `,@(eval args)`, or else conditionally process `args` either way, depending on what it turns out to actually be.

Answer (score 2):

Your `hc-call` should be a function, along the lines of

```
(defun hc-call (args)
  "Call herbstclient to with the given arguments."
  (apply #'process-lines "herbstclient" args))
```

BTW, while I'm here:

```
  (if (numberp arg)
      (setq stringified-args (cons (number-to-string arg) stringified-args))
    (setq stringified-args (cons arg stringified-args))))
```

is better written

```
  (setq stringified-args (cons (if (numberp arg) (number-to-string arg) arg) stringified-args))))
```

or

```
  (push (if (numberp arg) (number-to-string arg) arg) stringified-args)))
```